# Find previous Last Cost

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction stock database. It has both Sales and Receipts. I am looking to match the Stock Sale with the Last Cost at the time of the sale. I am trying to write the SQL query but cannot work out how to do the subquery or join properly

The data would look something like this:

```
STOCKCODE  DATE   TYPE    QTY  UNIT_VALUE  TOTAL_VALUE
ABC123     01/Dec RECEIPT 10   100.00      1000.00
ABC123     02/Dec SALES   -8   120.00       960.00
ABC123     03/Dec RECEIPT 10   110.00      1100.00
ABC123     04/Dec SALES  -12   120.00      1440.00
```

So the Last Cost at the moment is $110.00.
But I want to find the Last Cost at the time I sold the 8 units on 02 Dec (being $100.00)

Comment: Please post your schema definition for the tables

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  Can you better explain what your logic is?  Also, please tag with the database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. What I am trying to do is look backwards and work out what the cost of the goods I sold were at the time I sold them. So on the 02 December I sold 8 units that I had purchased for $100 each. But since my master Table of Stock Items only has Last Cost which is updated with each Receipt, it currently displays the value of $110

Comment: When you questions is solved, please "accept" the answer that solved or helped solve it. You get 2 reputation points when you do this, and others will know that your questions has been solved. Please do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using an apply operator would work here:

```
select t.*, oa.last_value
from yourtable t
outer apply (
   select top(1) unit_value as last_value
   from yourtable y
   where t.stockcode = y.stockcode
   and y.type = 'RECEIPT'
   and y.[date] < t.[date]
   order by y.[date] DESC
   ) oa
```

I'm not certain if [type] plays a part in this logic or not, I suspect it does.

below there is a small addiion to the query usg coalesce(): see [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcfb9/2)

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
    ([STOCKCODE] varchar(6), [DATE] datetime, [TYPE] varchar(7), [QTY] int, [UNIT_VALUE] int, [TOTAL_VALUE] int)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable 
    ([STOCKCODE], [DATE], [TYPE], [QTY], [UNIT_VALUE], [TOTAL_VALUE])
VALUES
    ('ABC123', '2001-12-01 00:00:00', 'RECEIPT', 10, 100.00, 1000.00),
    ('ABC123', '2001-12-02 00:00:00', 'SALES', -8, 120.00, 960.00),
    ('ABC123', '2001-12-03 00:00:00', 'RECEIPT', 10, 110.00, 1100.00),
    ('ABC123', '2001-12-04 00:00:00', 'SALES', -12, 120.00, 1440.00)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*, coalesce(oa.last_value,unit_value) last_value
from yourtable t
outer apply (
   select top(1) unit_value as last_value
   from yourtable y
   where t.stockcode = y.stockcode
   and y.type = 'RECEIPT'
   and y.[date] < t.[date]
   order by y.[date] DESC
   ) oa
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcfb9/2/0)**:

```
| STOCKCODE |                 DATE |    TYPE | QTY | UNIT_VALUE | TOTAL_VALUE | last_value |
|-----------|----------------------|---------|-----|------------|-------------|------------|
|    ABC123 | 2001-12-01T00:00:00Z | RECEIPT |  10 |        100 |        1000 |        100 |
|    ABC123 | 2001-12-02T00:00:00Z |   SALES |  -8 |        120 |         960 |        100 |
|    ABC123 | 2001-12-03T00:00:00Z | RECEIPT |  10 |        110 |        1100 |        100 |
|    ABC123 | 2001-12-04T00:00:00Z |   SALES | -12 |        120 |        1440 |        110 |
```

Comment: When I run this I get NULL in the first 2 lines in the "Last_Value" field

Comment: I added to me answer, and now that there is a results table, can you tell me what isn't right?

Comment: the NULL is because there was no prior value to display, so I added a "fix" to that.